# How to find X > 2Y when Joint PDF is constant

Tags: probability

Following is my Joint PDF

$f(xy) = 0.0025 $  and x and y are defined over [0,20]

I have to find P(X > 2Y). How do I do that?
If I draw this it is a box. Drawing a line cuts the box at (20,10). How to get further from that.

Comment: Do you mean the joint density function $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes....Let me change it

Comment: I was referring to $f(xy)$, which should be written as $f(x,y)$. I can't edit, since the change is just one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of the joint density function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{400} 1_{[0,20]\times [0,20]}(x,y)$ implies that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,20]\times [0,20]$. Try using the definition of $P((X,Y) \in A)$ for your region $A$. Your visualization can be a helpful first step.

**Solution**:

> \begin{align}P(X > 2Y) &= \int_0^{20} \int_0^{\frac{x}{2}} f(x,y)\, dy \,dx = \frac{1}{400} \int_0^{20} \int_0^{\frac{x}{2}} 1\, dy \,dx = \frac{1}{400} \int_0^{20} \frac{x}{2} \,dx \\&= \frac{1}{400} \left[\frac{x^2}{4}\right]_0^{20} = \frac{1}{4}\end{align}

Comment: I'm not a veteran here but I think usually for these kinds of questions (beginner/hw questions) it is recommended to give more of a hint rather than a full detailed answer, so that the original poster would eventually solve the question on his own

Comment: I added a hint and hid the solution in a spoiler environment to be more in the spirit of learning.

Answer (score 0):

"Drawing the line" is a good first step. Now, you get a region which represents the event $X>2Y$, which is everything inside the square $[0,20]\times [0,20]$ which is below the line you drew. All that is left is to calculate the integral of the PDF inside that region.

Note that this would be the same even for a different PDF defined in the square.

Answer (score 0):

Find the area of $\{(x,y)\in[0,20]^2\mid x>2y\}$ and multiply the result with $\frac1{400}$.

Then you found: $$P(X>2Y)=\mathbb E[X>2Y]=\int_0^{20}\int_0^{20}[x>2y]f(x,y)dydx$$ where $[x>2y]=1$ if $x>2y$ and $[x>2y]=0$ otherwise.